# Can I access "this" from a class property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to call `this` inside the `onClick` function which is inside the object, but I'm getting undefined in the console. Why is this happening?

Panel.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';

import PanelInterface from './Panel.Interface';
import Config from "../../Config";

const Panel: React.FC<PanelInterface> = (props) =>
{
    const config = new Config({
        panel : {
            onClick: function() {
                console.log(this);
            }
        }
    }).get();

    return (
        <div {...config.panel}/>
    );
};

export default Panel;
```

Config.ts:

```
export default class Config
{
    private readonly configuration: any;

    constructor(configuration: Object)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    public get(): any
    {
        return this.configuration;
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
undefined
undefined
```

Edit: Usage arrow functions has no effect. Also undefined in output.

Edit: The question was closed as a duplicate, although it is not. I managed to solve the problem by changing in Panel.Config:

```
export default new Config({
    panel : {
        className : css.panel,
        onClick: () => {
            console.log(this);
        }
    }
});
```

to:

```
const config = new Config({
    panel : {
        className : css.panel,
        onClick: () => {
            console.log(config);
        }
    }
});

export default config;
```

So in onClick instead of `this` I can use `config`.

Comment: What do you *want* it to be? A reference to the `Config` object? To `config.panel`? Something else?

Comment: I thought it would config.panel.

Comment: @dakovic323 - No, `this` inside a function in an object literal doesn't refer to the object being created ([more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers)). In this particular case you could just use `config.panel` instead of `this`. Otherwise, you'd have to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) it after the fact or similar.